# How can I check user id in Django in order to redirect him based on his role (admin or normal user)?

Tags: python, django

I want to use the same login form in order to redirect the user into the required page if he is an admin go to the admin page if not go to normal user page.

my view looks like:

```
def user_page(request,id):
    if 'id' in request.session:
        user = User.objects.get(id=request.session['id'])
        admin = user.admin
        if admin.filter(id=2):
            context = {
                'user': user,
                'companies': models.Companies.objects.all(),
                'type_list': models.Car_type.objects.all(),
                'rate': models.Rating.objects.all(),
                }
            return render(request, 'user.html', context)

        else:
           context = {
                'user': user,
                'companies': models.Companies.objects.all(),
                'type_list': models.Car_type.objects.all(),
                'rate': models.Rating.objects.all(),
            }
            return render(request, 'admin_main.html', context)
```

Comment: so where is your login view, where is your attempt

Comment: You are right I should left my code first but I'm not sure if it will help. thank you  I will edit the question with the code.